# How to install Edubuntu package in Ubuntu?

Tags: 10.10, installation, edubuntu

I have installed on my pc Ubuntu 10.10 and Edubuntu 11.04 in a USB. I had a problem with the installation of Edubuntu so I had to install ubuntu 10.10.

I want to install the desktop and all programs in Ubuntu. How I can do it?

Answer (score 4):

Install the metapackage called `edubuntu-desktop`, then logout and select Edubuntu as session.

Comment: How can i do it? i'm a basic user. i dont know what is a "metapackage" =(

Comment: Applications>Accesories>Terminal>Type `sudo apt-get install edbuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Let's call it package for simplicity. Just search for `edubuntu-desktop` in the Software Center, and click install.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the Ubuntu Software Centre and type *edubuntu* into the search field one of the top results will be the *Educational Desktop for Ubuntu*, installing that will provide all the Edubuntu software.

On that same page of results you will also see the individual bundles of software for pre-school upwards allowing you to install a specific set if you do not want to download everything from pre-school to third level (handy if on a slow internet connection).

Answer (score 1):

I just ran

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-edu-preschool
```

and it started installing all the necessary packages.

> Installation on an existing Ubuntu system
>   Edubuntu provides application bundles that group educational software by grade level. You can install from the Education category in the "Software Center" entry in the Applications menu or installing the following packages using your favorite package manager:
>
> ubuntu-edu-preschool - Preschool (
>   ubuntu-edu-primary - Primary ( ages 6-12) educational application bundle
>   ubuntu-edu-secondary - Secondary ( ages 13-18) educational application bundle
>   ubuntu-edu-tertiary - Tertiary ( university level ) educational application bundle
>   You can also install all Edubuntu packages, including artwork by installing the edubuntu-desktop package.

[Edunbuntu packages](https://www.edubuntu.org/download)

Answer (score 0):

Edubuntu, the desktop environment specially suited for schools and school students can be installed along your existing desktop environment. You can search it in the Software Center as mentioned above or also do it from the [Ubuntu Apps webpage](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/edubuntu-desktop/). Make sure you select Ubuntu (maverick) from the right-hand side under "Available Options"

[image]

Alternatively, you could also install the desktop environment from your terminal (*Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal *) using this command - `sudo apt-get install edubuntu-desktop` The *edubuntu-desktop* is a metapackage, meaning it holds links to the other packages that need to be installed to get the Edubuntu desktop environment. In short you could think of it like pointers or shortcut icons on your desktop. So when you say install the edubuntu-desktop metapackage, it'll install all the programs and stuff that constitute the edubuntu desktop environment.

Once that is installed, in any of the two above methods, the desktop environment should be selectable from the login page.

Comment: Upvoted the two answers above. Wrote this 'coz I thought all the info with a web-link should exist as an answer in one place. Sorry if that offends you.